# Bottom bar help text missing in IntelliJ New UI

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm

On the old UI, when hovering over an icon, a help text was displayed in the bottom of the editor, example:
[image]

In the New UI, the bottom part is missing.
Any idea on how to re-add it?

Upgrading to new UI for both Webstorm and Pycharm

Comment: View | Appearance | Status Bar?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that navigation bar was also on the bottom.
Once i moved it to Top, then the functionality worked again.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: How did you move the navigation bar to top? I have the same issue but no idea how to solve it.